# how to close a custom class like BubbleShowcase : UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, custom-view, showcaseview

i have a class

```
public class BubbleShowCase: UIView {

   public func dismiss() {
        animateDisappearance()
    }
}
```

how can i call that dismiss function on my View Controller ?
i want to dismiss that custom view on custom tap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever view you have `BubbleShowCase` what you need to dismiss is to remove it from its superView like

```
public class BubbleShowCase: UIView {

    public func dismiss() {
        self.removeFromSuperview()
     }
 }
```

and if you want to animate it you can do that as well

```
public class BubbleShowCase: UIView {
  
    public func dismiss() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: duration, animations: {
        self.alpha = 0
    }) { (completed) in
        guard completed else { return }
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: how to call that dissmiss function from my view controller ?

Comment: `yourview.dismiss()` simply